# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges Oracle Toad XE 11g

Tags: oracle, apache, tomcat, privilege

I have created users `KEN_ROA_DB` and `KEN_ROA_CORE_DB` respectively. I did the following commands when creating the users:

```
CREATE USER KEN_ROA_DB IDENTIFIED BY KEN_ROA_DB;
GRANT DBA TO KEN_ROA_DB WITH ADMIN OPTION;
CREATE USER KEN_ROA_CORE_DB IDENTIFIED BY KEN_ROA_CORE_DB;
GRANT DBA TO KEN_ROA_CORE_DB WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

All the respective tables have been created in Toad Oracle XE.

Below are the alter commands I am attempting to make which result in ORA-01031 and the full Apache tomcat logs are beneath them.

```
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_HISTORY_OFFICER add constraint FK_4a9odjukq4jwvn0m4qtwnve7b foreign key (Post_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_HISTORY_OFFICER add constraint FK_7rhki5ae41hcmac2yo7okau71 foreign key (TITLE_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_INSP add constraint FK_op8ivnn55lksto8qwhse8vyxn foreign key (category_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_MODULE_EVENT add constraint FK_9eg9yt704t9mife1o5sn74b9d foreign key (triggeredBy_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_k77i8jorltfmt5ox25ec70rug foreign key (occupation_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_6kk4yk1a9b0pu8kvi0hlci881 foreign key (Post_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_e0ml19qxoetw3qx0c329k51om foreign key (TITLE_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_chqvowumc503aldycrgqmwket foreign key (DISTRICT_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE    
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_i9hcyde4at7r4a9r6xb3xxdsp foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING_REG add constraint FK_bot557sbceij09eh8gpeq7r1g foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_SCANNED_DOC add constraint FK_sp8fiaq0wosh9jesuvfw1sdy5 foreign key (CATEGORY_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.CATEGORY
alter table ken_roa_db.Association add constraint FK_nitrcynejhgp2veeogsuhv7l8 foreign key (district_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.Association add constraint FK_l32q88lvymjwqf2xfhqp3d92v foreign key (type_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_DUTY_SCHED_REG add constraint FK_8v6rvduxvvcb8t8npq2ejr0mo foreign key (INSP_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_DUTY_SCHED_REG add constraint FK_3v4ki451r75aefxcist1aopaa foreign key (MGMT_SUPP_OFFICER_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF  
alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_ROSTER add constraint FK_r0hgetwi4iwgmu40r9wwc5lrl foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.TU_CONFED_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_sbmglpaeco4kgfvvveajeh6ph foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF    
alter table ken_roa_db.TU_FED_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_dhyar2a2f2lw9snfpibmnn774 foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.TU_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_ibq61ds67ex72a8n87grpuyg3 foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
alter table ken_roa_db.TU_REGNO_MAPPING_REG add constraint FK_byy45hop09brbpl6hqt8miv0v foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
```

Apache Logs:

```
05-May-2015 22:19:32.918 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxJobName on ken_roa_core_db.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE (JOB_NAME)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.919 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:32.945 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxSkipItem on ken_roa_core_db.BATCH_SKIP_ITEM (JOB_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.946 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:32.951 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxJobExecution on ken_roa_core_db.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.952 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:32.959 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxCategoryTypeId on ken_roa_core_db.CATEGORY (CATEGORY_TYPE_ID)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.960 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:32.975 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxUserModuleUsage on ken_roa_core_db.MODULE_USAGE (USER_ID)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.975 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:32.992 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index idxReport on ken_roa_core_db.REPORT_PARAMETER (REPORT_ID)
05-May-2015 22:19:32.992 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

05-May-2015 22:19:33.000 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_HISTORY_OFFICER add constraint FK_4a9odjukq4jwvn0m4qtwnve7b foreign key (Post_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.001 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.012 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_HISTORY_OFFICER add constraint FK_7rhki5ae41hcmac2yo7okau71 foreign key (TITLE_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.013 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.023 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_INSP add constraint FK_op8ivnn55lksto8qwhse8vyxn foreign key (category_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.023 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.030 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_MODULE_EVENT add constraint FK_9eg9yt704t9mife1o5sn74b9d foreign key (triggeredBy_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.030 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.041 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_k77i8jorltfmt5ox25ec70rug foreign key (occupation_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.042 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.055 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_6kk4yk1a9b0pu8kvi0hlci881 foreign key (Post_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.055 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.068 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_OFFICER add constraint FK_e0ml19qxoetw3qx0c329k51om foreign key (TITLE_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.068 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.078 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_chqvowumc503aldycrgqmwket foreign key (DISTRICT_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.079 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.092 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_i9hcyde4at7r4a9r6xb3xxdsp foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.093 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.105 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_REGNO_MAPPING_REG add constraint FK_bot557sbceij09eh8gpeq7r1g foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.105 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.112 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.ASSN_SCANNED_DOC add constraint FK_sp8fiaq0wosh9jesuvfw1sdy5 foreign key (CATEGORY_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.CATEGORY
05-May-2015 22:19:33.113 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.123 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.Association add constraint FK_nitrcynejhgp2veeogsuhv7l8 foreign key (district_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.123 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.135 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.Association add constraint FK_l32q88lvymjwqf2xfhqp3d92v foreign key (type_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE
05-May-2015 22:19:33.136 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.147 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_DUTY_SCHED_REG add constraint FK_8v6rvduxvvcb8t8npq2ejr0mo foreign key (INSP_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.147 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.159 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_DUTY_SCHED_REG add constraint FK_3v4ki451r75aefxcist1aopaa foreign key (MGMT_SUPP_OFFICER_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.160 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.170 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.INSPN_MTHLY_ROSTER add constraint FK_r0hgetwi4iwgmu40r9wwc5lrl foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.171 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.181 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.TU_CONFED_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_sbmglpaeco4kgfvvveajeh6ph foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.182 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.191 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.TU_FED_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_dhyar2a2f2lw9snfpibmnn774 foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.192 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.201 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.TU_REGNO_MAPPING add constraint FK_ibq61ds67ex72a8n87grpuyg3 foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.202 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.212 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table ken_roa_db.TU_REGNO_MAPPING_REG add constraint FK_byy45hop09brbpl6hqt8miv0v foreign key (user_ID) references ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF
05-May-2015 22:19:33.213 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

05-May-2015 22:19:33.214 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000232: Schema update complete
2015-05-05 22:19:35,328 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - indexFrom is 0 and numRowPerPage is 9999999
2015-05-05 22:19:35,328 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - Query is DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(com.kenfook.core.role.db.po.RolePO:this[][]))
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE this_
Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.ID as ID1_82_0_, this_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_82_0_, this_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_82_0_, this_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION4_82_0_, this_.NAME as NAME5_82_0_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE this_ ) where rownum <= ?
2015-05-05 22:19:35,392 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - processQuery: Row count is 0 and list size is 0
2015-05-05 22:19:35,420 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - indexFrom is 0 and numRowPerPage is 9999999
2015-05-05 22:19:35,420 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - Query is DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(com.kenfook.core.role.db.po.RolePO:this[][]))
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE this_
Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.ID as ID1_82_0_, this_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_82_0_, this_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_82_0_, this_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION4_82_0_, this_.NAME as NAME5_82_0_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE this_ ) where rownum <= ?
2015-05-05 22:19:35,430 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - processQuery: Row count is 0 and list size is 0
In MyFilterSecuriySource 1 : urlPatternList size = 0
In MyFilterSecuriySource 1 : defaultPatternList size = 0


#########################################################


#########################################################
05-May-2015 22:19:44.548 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass Creating Service {http://webservice.kenfook.com/}AssociationWSImplService from class com.kenfook.webservice.AssociationWS
05-May-2015 22:19:46.241 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination Setting the server's publish address to be /AssociationWS
2015-05-05 22:19:51,372 INFO  com.kenfook.settings.AppContextLoaderListener -
!!!!Web Application Context is loaded!!!!

2015-05-05 22:19:51,372 INFO  com.kenfook.settings.AppContextLoaderListener -
!!!!LOADING DATA FROM PRELOADER!!!!

2015-05-05 22:19:51,400 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.user.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl - In getByUsername, username is $$superadmin$$
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_87_6_, this_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_87_6_, this_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_87_6_, this_.ANSWER as ANSWER4_87_6_, this_.EMAIL as EMAIL5_87_6_, this_.JQUERY_THEME as JQUERY_THEME6_87_6_, this_.LAST_ACTION as LAST_ACTION7_87_6_, this_.LAST_LOGIN_TIME as LAST_LOGIN_TIME8_87_6_, this_.LAST_LOGOUT_TIME as LAST_LOGOUT_TIME9_87_6_, this_.LAST_UPDATED_PASSWORD as LAST_UPDATED_PASS10_87_6_, this_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD11_87_6_, this_.QUESTION as QUESTION12_87_6_, this_.RETRIES_RESET_PASSWORD as RETRIES_RESET_PAS13_87_6_, this_.RETRIES as RETRIES14_87_6_, this_.STATUS as STATUS15_87_6_, this_.TYPE_ID as TYPE_ID16_87_6_, this_.USERNAME as USERNAME17_87_6_, this_1_.ADDRESS1 as ADDRESS1_89_6_, this_1_.ADDRESS2 as ADDRESS2_89_6_, this_1_.ADDRESS3 as ADDRESS3_89_6_, this_1_.ADDRESS4 as ADDRESS4_89_6_, this_1_.ASSN_INSPECTOR_PRINCIPAL_ID as ASSN_INSPECTOR_PR13_89_6_, this_1_.ASSN_INSPECTOR_SENIOR_ID as ASSN_INSPECTOR_SE14_89_6_, this_1_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY
15_89_6_, this_1_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH5_89_6_, this_1_.GENDER as GENDER16_89_6_, this_1_.GRADE as GRADE17_89_6_, this_1_.MARITAL_STATUS as MARITAL_STATUS18_89_6_, this_1_.NAME as NAME6_89_6_, this_1_.PHONENO_HOME as PHONENO_HOME7_89_6_, this_1_.PHONENO_MOBILE as PHONENO_MOBILE8_89_6_, this_1_.PHONENO_OFFICE as PHONENO_OFFICE9_89_6_, this_1_.PLACE_OF_BIRTH as PLACE_OF_BIRTH10_89_6_, this_1_.SURNAME as SURNAME11_89_6_, this_1_.TITLE as TITLE19_89_6_, this_1_.TU_INSPECTOR_PRINCIPAL_ID as TU_INSPECTOR_PRIN20_89_6_, this_1_.TU_INSPECTOR_SENIOR_ID as TU_INSPECTOR_SENI21_89_6_, case when this_1_.ID is not null then 1 when this_.ID is not null then 0 end as clazz_6_, roles2_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_87_8_, rolepo3_.ID as ROLE_ID2_88_8_, rolepo3_.ID as ID1_82_0_, rolepo3_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_82_0_, rolepo3_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_82_0_, rolepo3_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION4_82_0_, rolepo3_.NAME as NAME5_82_0_, codevaluep4_.ID as ID1_68_1_, codevaluep4_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_N
AME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_68_1_, codevaluep4_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_68_1_, codevaluep4_.CODE as CODE4_68_1_, codevaluep4_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_68_1_, codevaluep4_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_68_1_, codevaluep4_.VALUE as VALUE7_68_1_, commonrefe5_.ID as ID1_69_2_, commonrefe5_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_2_, commonrefe5_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_2_, commonrefe5_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_2_, commonrefe5_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_2_, commonrefe5_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_2_, commonrefe6_.ID as ID1_69_3_, commonrefe6_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_3_, commonrefe6_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_3_, commonrefe6_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_3_, commonrefe6_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_3_, commonrefe6_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_3_, commonrefe7_.ID as ID1_69_4_, commonrefe7_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_4_, commonrefe7_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_4_, commonrefe7_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_4_, commonrefe7_.DESC
RIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_4_, commonrefe7_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_4_, commonrefe8_.ID as ID1_69_5_, commonrefe8_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_5_, commonrefe8_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_5_, commonrefe8_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_5_, commonrefe8_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_5_, commonrefe8_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_5_ from ken_roa_core_db.USERS this_ left outer join ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF this_1_ on this_.ID=this_1_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.USERS_ROLE roles2_ on this_.ID=roles2_.USER_ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.ROLE rolepo3_ on roles2_.ROLE_ID=rolepo3_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.CODEVALUE codevaluep4_ on this_1_.COUNTRY=codevaluep4_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe5_ on this_1_.GENDER=commonrefe5_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe6_ on this_1_.GRADE=commonrefe6_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe7_ on this_1_.MARITAL_STATUS=commo
nrefe7_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe8_ on this_1_.TITLE=commonrefe8_.ID where this_.USERNAME=?
2015-05-05 22:19:51,453 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.user.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl - In UserProxy, userPO is null
Hibernate: select this_.JOB_EXECUTION_ID as JOB_EXECUTION_ID1_61_1_, this_.CREATE_TIME as CREATE_TIME2_61_1_, this_.END_TIME as END_TIME3_61_1_, this_.EXIT_CODE as EXIT_CODE4_61_1_, this_.EXIT_MESSAGE as EXIT_MESSAGE5_61_1_, this_.JOB_INSTANCE_ID as JOB_INSTANCE_ID10_61_1_, this_.LAST_UPDATED as LAST_UPDATED6_61_1_, this_.START_TIME as START_TIME7_61_1_, this_.STATUS as STATUS8_61_1_, this_.VERSION as VERSION9_61_1_, batchjobin2_.JOB_INSTANCE_ID as JOB_INSTANCE_ID1_63_0_, batchjobin2_.JOB_KEY as JOB_KEY2_63_0_, batchjobin2_.JOB_NAME as JOB_NAME3_63_0_, batchjobin2_.VERSION as VERSION4_63_0_ from ken_roa_core_db.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION this_ inner join ken_roa_core_db.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE batchjobin2_ on this_.JOB_INSTANCE_ID=batchjobin2_.JOB_INSTANCE_ID where this_.END_TIME is null and this_.STATUS<>?
2015-05-05 22:19:51,485 INFO  com.kenfook.settings.PreLoader - System did not find any jobs to abandon
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/domain/**/*.class
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/dataimport/**/*.class
2015-05-05 22:19:54,055 DEBUG com.kenfook.cache.GridAttributeCache - Time taken to load cache grid is StopWatch 'Cached Grid Attribute': running time (millis) = 2553
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/domain/**/*.class
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/db/po/**/*.class
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/domain/**/*.class
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:web/action/**/*.class
pachageSearchPath = classpath*:com/*/*/*/domain/**/*.class
2015-05-05 22:19:55,141 DEBUG com.kenfook.settings.PreLoader - Time taken to load cache in PreLoader is StopWatch 'Load caching in PreLoader': running time (millis) = 3648
2015-05-05 22:19:55,162 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - indexFrom is 1 and numRowPerPage is 999999
2015-05-05 22:19:55,162 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - Query is DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(com.kenfook.core.roletemporary.db.po.RoleTemporaryPO:this[][]))
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE_TEMPORARY this_
Hibernate: select * from ( select this_.ID as ID1_86_7_, this_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_86_7_, this_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_86_7_, this_.REMARK as REMARK4_86_7_, this_.GRANTED as GRANTED5_86_7_, this_.REVOKED as REVOKED6_86_7_, this_.role_ID as role_ID9_86_7_, this_.TIME_END as TIME_END7_86_7_, this_.TIME_START as TIME_START8_86_7_, this_.user_ID as user_ID10_86_7_, rolepo2_.ID as ID1_82_0_, rolepo2_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_82_0_, rolepo2_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_82_0_, rolepo2_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION4_82_0_, rolepo2_.NAME as NAME5_82_0_, userstaffp3_.ID as ID1_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.ANSWER as ANSWER4_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.EMAIL as EMAIL5_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.JQUERY_THEME as JQUERY_THEME6_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.LAST_ACTION as LAST_ACTION7_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.LAST_LOGIN_TIME as LAST_LOGIN_TIME8_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.LAST_LOGOUT_TIME as LAST_
LOGOUT_TIME9_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.LAST_UPDATED_PASSWORD as LAST_UPDATED_PASS10_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD11_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.QUESTION as QUESTION12_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.RETRIES_RESET_PASSWORD as RETRIES_RESET_PAS13_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.RETRIES as RETRIES14_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.STATUS as STATUS15_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.TYPE_ID as TYPE_ID16_87_1_, userstaffp3_1_.USERNAME as USERNAME17_87_1_, userstaffp3_.ADDRESS1 as ADDRESS1_89_1_, userstaffp3_.ADDRESS2 as ADDRESS2_89_1_, userstaffp3_.ADDRESS3 as ADDRESS3_89_1_, userstaffp3_.ADDRESS4 as ADDRESS4_89_1_, userstaffp3_.ASSN_INSPECTOR_PRINCIPAL_ID as ASSN_INSPECTOR_PR13_89_1_, userstaffp3_.ASSN_INSPECTOR_SENIOR_ID as ASSN_INSPECTOR_SE14_89_1_, userstaffp3_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY15_89_1_, userstaffp3_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH5_89_1_, userstaffp3_.GENDER as GENDER16_89_1_, userstaffp3_.GRADE as GRADE17_89_1_, userstaffp3_.MARITAL_STATUS as MARITAL_STATUS18_89_1_, userstaffp3_.NAME as NAME6_89_1_, userstaffp3_.PHONENO_H
OME as PHONENO_HOME7_89_1_, userstaffp3_.PHONENO_MOBILE as PHONENO_MOBILE8_89_1_, userstaffp3_.PHONENO_OFFICE as PHONENO_OFFICE9_89_1_, userstaffp3_.PLACE_OF_BIRTH as PLACE_OF_BIRTH10_89_1_, userstaffp3_.SURNAME as SURNAME11_89_1_, userstaffp3_.TITLE as TITLE19_89_1_, userstaffp3_.TU_INSPECTOR_PRINCIPAL_ID as TU_INSPECTOR_PRIN20_89_1_, userstaffp3_.TU_INSPECTOR_SENIOR_ID as TU_INSPECTOR_SENI21_89_1_, codevaluep4_.ID as ID1_68_2_, codevaluep4_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_68_2_, codevaluep4_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_68_2_, codevaluep4_.CODE as CODE4_68_2_, codevaluep4_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_68_2_, codevaluep4_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_68_2_, codevaluep4_.VALUE as VALUE7_68_2_, commonrefe5_.ID as ID1_69_3_, commonrefe5_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_3_, commonrefe5_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_3_, commonrefe5_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_3_, commonrefe5_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_3_, commonrefe5_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_3_, commonrefe
6_.ID as ID1_69_4_, commonrefe6_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_4_, commonrefe6_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_4_, commonrefe6_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_4_, commonrefe6_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_4_, commonrefe6_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_4_, commonrefe7_.ID as ID1_69_5_, commonrefe7_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_5_, commonrefe7_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_5_, commonrefe7_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_5_, commonrefe7_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_5_, commonrefe7_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_5_, commonrefe8_.ID as ID1_69_6_, commonrefe8_.ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME as ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAM2_69_6_, commonrefe8_.OWNER_ID as OWNER_ID3_69_6_, commonrefe8_.CATEGORY as CATEGORY4_69_6_, commonrefe8_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION5_69_6_, commonrefe8_.LOOKUP_TYPE_ID as LOOKUP_TYPE_ID6_69_6_ from ken_roa_core_db.ROLE_TEMPORARY this_ inner join ken_roa_core_db.ROLE rolepo2_ on this_.role_ID=rolepo2_.ID inner join ken_roa_core_db.USER_STAFF userstaffp3_ on this_.us
er_ID=userstaffp3_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.USERS userstaffp3_1_ on userstaffp3_.ID=userstaffp3_1_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.CODEVALUE codevaluep4_ on userstaffp3_.COUNTRY=codevaluep4_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe5_ on userstaffp3_.GENDER=commonrefe5_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe6_ on userstaffp3_.GRADE=commonrefe6_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe7_ on userstaffp3_.MARITAL_STATUS=commonrefe7_.ID left outer join ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE commonrefe8_ on userstaffp3_.TITLE=commonrefe8_.ID ) where rownum <= ?
2015-05-05 22:19:55,192 DEBUG com.kenfook.core.common.db.CommonHibernate - processQuery: Row count is 0 and list size is 0
Hibernate: select ken_roa_core_db.SEQ_ROLE.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into ken_roa_core_db.ROLE (ENTITY_DISPLAY_NAME, OWNER_ID, DESCRIPTION, NAME, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
05-May-2015 22:19:55.439 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
05-May-2015 22:19:55.439 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

2015-05-05 22:19:55,446 ERROR com.kenfook.settings.AppContextLoaderListener - could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.e
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permissions from `ken_roa_core_db` schema tables to `ken_roa_db`. At least `REFERENCES` option, for example:

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON ken_roa_core_db.COMMON_REFERENCE TO ken_roa_db
```